# Adding ports to a random list of IP addresses

Tags: ruby, ip-address

I have created an application that I will be using for pentesting. It creates a list of random IP addresses, pings them, and adds ports to them (but it's not complete).

It works exactly how it should, and I just want to know if there's a better way to write this specific aspect of the program.

```
require 'colored'
require 'timeout'

def create_possibles
  puts "[INFO]Attempting to ping generated IP addresses.".green.bold
  ports = %w(80 443 1935 2222 3128 3130 7808 8080 8081 8085 8089 8090 8102 8104 8106 8118 8119 8123 8888 8898 9000 9090 9797 9999 10000 10052 10053 10059 10088 12345 18000 18001 18008 37564 40080 55336 59998)
    10.times do 
      ip = Array.new(4){rand(256)}.join('.')
      Timeout::timeout(5) do
        ping = `ping -n 1 #{ip}` 
        if ping =~ /Received = 1/ 
          puts "[SUCCESS]Proxy created for IP: #{ip}".green.bold
          File.open("proxies.txt", "a+") {|s| s.puts("#{ip}:#{ports[0]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[1]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[2]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[3]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[4]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[5]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[6]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[7]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[8]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[9]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[10]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[11]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[12]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[13]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[14]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[15]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[16]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[17]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[18]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[19]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[20]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[21]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[22]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[23]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[24]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[25]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[26]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[27]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[28]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[29]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[30]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[31]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[32]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[33]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[34]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[35]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[36]}")}
        else
          puts "[ERROR]IP failed to ping: #{ip}".red.bold
          next
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Usage example:

> ```
> [INFO]Attempting to ping generated IP addresses.
> [ERROR]IP failed to ping: 197.51.232.17
> [ERROR]IP failed to ping: 241.205.115.165
> [SUCCESS]Proxy created for IP: 217.123.77.145
> [ERROR]IP failed to ping: 16.253.31.19
> [SUCCESS]Proxy created for IP: 27.209.123.149
> [ERROR]IP failed to ping: 154.156.130.254
> [ERROR]IP failed to ping: 229.29.20.2
> [ERROR]IP failed to ping: 11.57.201.170
> [ERROR]IP failed to ping: 254.99.203.92
> [ERROR]IP failed to ping: 153.2.170.205
> ```

Example of text file:

> ```
> 217.123.77.145:80
> 217.123.77.145:443
> 217.123.77.145:1935
> 217.123.77.145:2222
> 217.123.77.145:3128
> 217.123.77.145:3130
> 217.123.77.145:7808
> 217.123.77.145:8080
> 217.123.77.145:8081
> 217.123.77.145:8085
> 217.123.77.145:8089
> 217.123.77.145:8090
> 217.123.77.145:8102
> 217.123.77.145:8104
> 217.123.77.145:8106
> 217.123.77.145:8118
> 217.123.77.145:8119
> 217.123.77.145:8123
> 217.123.77.145:8888
> 217.123.77.145:8898
> 217.123.77.145:9000
> 217.123.77.145:9090
> 217.123.77.145:9797
> 217.123.77.145:9999
> 217.123.77.145:10000
> 217.123.77.145:10052
> 217.123.77.145:10053
> 217.123.77.145:10059
> 217.123.77.145:10088
> 217.123.77.145:12345
> 217.123.77.145:18000
> 217.123.77.145:18001
> 217.123.77.145:18008
> 217.123.77.145:37564
> 217.123.77.145:40080
> 217.123.77.145:55336
> 217.123.77.145:59998
> 27.209.123.149:80
> 27.209.123.149:443
> 27.209.123.149:1935
> 27.209.123.149:2222
> 27.209.123.149:3128
> 27.209.123.149:3130
> 27.209.123.149:7808
> 27.209.123.149:8080
> 27.209.123.149:8081
> 27.209.123.149:8085
> 27.209.123.149:8089
> 27.209.123.149:8090
> 27.209.123.149:8102
> 27.209.123.149:8104
> 27.209.123.149:8106
> 27.209.123.149:8118
> 27.209.123.149:8119
> 27.209.123.149:8123
> 27.209.123.149:8888
> 27.209.123.149:8898
> 27.209.123.149:9000
> 27.209.123.149:9090
> 27.209.123.149:9797
> 27.209.123.149:9999
> 27.209.123.149:10000
> 27.209.123.149:10052
> 27.209.123.149:10053
> 27.209.123.149:10059
> 27.209.123.149:10088
> 27.209.123.149:12345
> 27.209.123.149:18000
> 27.209.123.149:18001
> 27.209.123.149:18008
> 27.209.123.149:37564
> 27.209.123.149:40080
> 27.209.123.149:55336
> 27.209.123.149:59998
> ```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some great answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notes on your code:

- Wrap lines to 80-100 chars, longer lines are unreadable.
- `ping -n 1 #{ip}`. Whenever possible, use specific Ruby libraries instead of external commands, it will be more portable (i.e. [net-ping](https://github.com/djberg96/net-ping))
- `"#{ip}:#{ports[0]}`. That calls for a loop.
- What is this `next` doing?

I'd write:

```
require 'colored'
require 'net/ping'

def create_possibles
  ports = %w(
    80 443 1935 2222 3128 3130 7808 8080 8081 8085 8089 8090 8102 8104 8106 
    8118 8119 8123 8888 8898 9000 9090 9797 9999 10000 10052 10053 10059 
    10088 12345 18000 18001 18008 37564 40080 55336 59998
  )

  puts("[INFO] Attempting to ping generated IP addresses.".green.bold)
  10.times do 
    ip = Array.new(4) { rand(256) }.join(".")

    if Net::Ping::ICMP.new(ip).ping? 
      puts("[SUCCESS] Proxy created for IP: #{ip}".green.bold)
      File.open("proxies.txt", "a+") do |fd|
        ports.each { |port| fd.puts("#{ip}:#{port}") }
      end
    else
      puts("[ERROR] IP failed to ping: #{ip}".red.bold)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Why use `map` instead of `Array.new`?

Comment: I thought it looked more declarative, but I like Array.new(size) too.

Comment: Alright now let me ask you this, it's not one of my stated questions but would it be possible to loop finding the ips until the file containing the proxies gets to a certain size say 71826kb?

Comment: Yes, there are many alternatives. You can add a `while` that checks either the file size ( `File.size(path)`) or keep  a variable with the bytes you have written to it.